# How to combine output from Get-CimInstance and Get-WMIObject functions

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi

I have got 2 powershell scripts, which I have mentioned below. I am looking for a way to combine both of these scripts. However I am unable to do so as one of the script is using CIM method and the other one is using the WMI method.

What I am trying to accomplish, is to provide the last reboot time and free space available of the same server (User has to enter the server name and on pressing `Enter` it shows the last reboot time and free space available).

Script 1 (CIM Method) :

```
$Server = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your server  name'
Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $Server | select csname, lastbootuptime
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

Script 2 (WMI Method) :

```
$Server = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your server  name'
Get-WMIObject Win32_Logicaldisk -ComputerName $Server | Select PSComputername,DeviceID, @{Name="Total_Size_GB";Expression={$_.Size/1GB -as [int]}}, @{Name="Free_Space_GB";Expression={[math]::Round($_.Freespace/1GB,2)}}
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the results of your queries in a variable. Then create a `psobject` with the values you are interested in from each function. [You can find out more about New-Object psobject here.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2009/12/04/new-object-psobject-property-hashtable/)

```
$Server = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your server  name'

$myCimResp = Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $Server | select csname, lastbootuptime
$myWmiResp = Get-WMIObject Win32_Logicaldisk -ComputerName $Server | Select PSComputername,DeviceID, @{Name="Total_Size_GB";Expression={$_.Size/1GB -as [int]}}, @{Name="Free_Space_GB";Expression={[math]::Round($_.Freespace/1GB,2)}}

$theThingIActuallyWant = New-Object psobject -Property @{
    LastRebootTime = $myCimResp.lastbootuptime
    FreeSpace      = $myWmiResp.Free_Space_GB
}

# A couple of ways to print; delete 1, keep 1
Write-Output $theThingIActuallyWant      # Print to screen with implicit rules
$theThingIActuallyWant | Format-Table    # Print to screen with explicit table formatting


Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

Comment: @gms0ulman Not sure if I am doing anything wrong, but I am getting this error :

+ $theThingIActuallyWant = New-Object psobject =Property @{
+                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
 
New-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Collections.Hashtable'

Comment: ....... 

At C:\Users\XXXXXXX\XXXXXX\script.ps1:6 char:26
+ $theThingIActuallyWant = New-Object psobject =Property @{
+                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Comment: @SharatPadmanabhan I think that's my bad; corrected typo from `=Property` to `-Property` and `$myWmiResp.lastbootuptime` to `$myWmiResp.Free_Space_GB`